# SQL Server: nonclustered indexes after MERGE (insert / update)

Tags: sql-server, optimization, indexing

I'm new to SQL Server, trying to optimize a procedure I received from ex-colleague (and I can't ask him).

At the final step, the procedure updates a large table using a `MERGE` statement. After that, it drops two nonclustered indexes and creates them again. What is the purpose of doing that? Aren't collected statistics for optimizer being recollected regularly? Is recreating indexes the only way to provide optimizer with fresh statistics?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After that, it drops two nonclustered indexes and creates them again. What is the purpose
> of doing that?

To organize them into less space without possibly page splits that may have happened during the merge. Generally it is NOT needed - like at all. It MAY make sense, but it is much better to actually analyze the index statistics about page splits before doing that unless you can be sure it is beneficial on every load.

> Aren't collected statistics for optimizer being recollected regularly?

They are, but reoganizing the indices may make them more efficient. As data changes, data in index pages changes and when it overflows then a page is split. This leads to the index (nto the statistics on it) being unbalanced over time, which may lead to additional IO load.

> Is recreating indexes the only way to provide optimizer with fresh statistics?

No. But you do not do it for statistics in the first place. You can just update the statistics if you want this. You do it to get an efficient index.